# pytest testing methods that are calling methods with global variables as arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-s3, pytest, monkeypatching

I am trying to test src_data_csv() function but since I am calling all these different functions inside it I wasn't sure what will be the best way to test it.

```
def src_data_csv() -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Reads csv file on s3 for specific columns into pandas df.
    :return: df with the dstatuschangeddate and sgroupid columns
    """
    # csv
    namespaces_csv = list_all_namespace_prefixes(get_prefix_src_data("oe", "csv"))
    file_paths = list_all_s3_files(namespaces_csv)
    # get the data from all files in the list and append it to one file
    csv_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for file_path in file_paths:
        output_file = bucket_uri(file_path)
        csv_df = csv_df.append(
            pd.read_csv(
                output_file,
                usecols=["name", "date"],
                parse_dates= ["date"]
            )
        )
    return csv_df
```

One way I can do this is by using pytest patching for  `list_all_namespace_prefixes`

```
mocker.patch("lhp_report.utilities.list_all_namespace_prefixes",
             return_value="src_data/extract/oncoemr/order_charge_history/")
```

and also for `list_all_s3_files()`

```
mocker.patch("lhp_report.utilities.list_all_s3_files",
             return_value="src_data/extract/oncoemr/order_charge_history/src_data/extract/oncoemr/order_charge_history/order_charge_history_securemock_oncoemr.csv.gz")
```

and eventually for `bucket_uri()` but since every function I patch, it overrides previous function calls so it doesn't seem like the best approach.

Another way is to change `src_data_csv()` so that instead of calling other functions inside it, it I pass in these values as parameters. It is also a tedious process.

None of these options seems like a good option so I was wondering if `monkeypatching` will be a good option? I have never done testing before so this is turning out to be quite challenging.

Maybe I can patch `list_all_namespace_prefixes` so it can use the result to call `list_all_s3_files()` and then monkeypatch `list_all_contents()` because it's using global variables in it's parameters.

For reference this is `list_all_s3_files()` function:

```
    """
    Returns a list of the file names/keys under a given S3 bucket and prefix.
    """
    result = []
    for path in src_path:
        file_names = list_all_contents(prefix=path, format="Contents")
        result.extend(file_names)
    return result
```

And here is `list_all_contents()` , fyi i wanted to do monkey patching so I can specify it's parameter to my fixture boto3 client. list_all_contents() because this function is using global variables:

```
def list_all_contents(
    prefix: str,
    format: str,
    bucket_name: str = BUCKET_NAME,
    s3_client: "boto3.client" = s3_client,
) -> list:
    """
    :param prefix: path for the s3 object where all the files are located
    :param format: Contents will get all keys/files and CommonPrefixes will get all namespaces in a given prefix
    :return: List object of file namespaces/keys under a given S3 bucket and prefix.
    """

    s3_result = s3_client.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter="/"
    )

    file_list = []
    # Contents returns metadata about each object

    for key in s3_result.get(format, []):
        if format == "Contents":
            file_list.append(key["Key"])
        else:
            file_list.append(key["Prefix"])

    return file_list
```

Comment: you're running in to the issue that the logical complexity of your function is to large. the more mocking and patching you have to do means the more complexity your function has. try to break `src_data_csv` in to even smaller functions

Comment: I was able to break it up to just work on reading CSV data. And pass the values of other functions as an input to src_data_csv